# how to use custom option.phtml instead of core in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to use custom option.phtml file instead of magento's "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml".
Can anyone tell me how can i use this without touch core files.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in app/design folder, can do for only app/code folder.
If you want to change the file in app/design folder, then you have to take a backup of the file and edit.